# Finding the amount of nitrous oxide produced in the reaction between lead sulfide and nitric acid

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws, stoichiometry

> Lead(II) sulfide dissolves in excess nitric acid according to the equation below. Calculate the volume of $\ce{NO{(g)}}$ at $\pu{27 ^\circ C}$ and $\pu{1.10 atm}$ produced from $\pu{4.7 g}$ of $\ce{PbS(s)}$.
>
> $$\ce{3PbS{(s)} + 2NO3–{(aq)} + 8H+{(aq)} -> 3Pb^2+{(aq)} + 3S{(s)} + 2NO{(g)} + 4H2O{(l)}}$$
>
> a) $\pu{0.29 L}$
> b) $\pu{0.44 L}$
> c) $\pu{0.66 L}$
> d) $\pu{30 L}$
> e) $\pu{45 L}$

I used the ideal gas formula and converted the mass of $\ce{PbS}$ into number of moles of $\ce{PbS}$ however got the answer b) $\pu{0.44 L}$ which is incorrect. The correct answer is a) however I am unsure about. Why this is?

Comment: You skipped a step. You got the number of moles of $\ce{PbS}$, that's good. Now you need to find the number of moles of $\ce{NO}$ which result from the reaction, and only then apply the ideal gas law.

Comment: Nitrous oxide is not nitric oxide, i.e., NO!

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to calculate the number of moles of $\ce{PbS}$:

$$n(\ce{PbS}) = \frac{\pu{4.7 g}}{\pu{239 g mol-1}} = \pu{0.0197 mol}$$

The next step is to calculate how many moles of $\ce{NO}$ will be produced based on the stoichiometry of the reaction. As stated in a comment, it looks like this is the step that was left out of your calculations. Because only $\pu{2 mol}$ of $\ce{NO}$ are produced for every $\pu{3 mol}$ of $\ce{PbS}$, only $2/3$ of $\pu{0.0197 mol}$, or $\pu{0.0131 mol}$ $\ce{NO}$ will be formed.

At this point we know all of the variables required to invoke the ideal gas law:

$$
\begin{align}
V(\ce{NO}) &= \frac{nRT}{p}\\
 &= \frac{\pu{0.0131 mol} \times \pu{0.0821 L atm mol-1 K-1} \times \pu{300K}}{\pu{1.10 atm}}\\   
 &= \pu{0.29 L}
\end{align}
$$

And this gives us the correct answer of *a*. Again, as your answer was off by a factor of $2/3$, it is pretty clear that the second step above regarding the stoichiometry of the reaction is the only step that you left out of your calculations.